# where database store in iphone simulator (for Mac OS)?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

i create a application.Whose, Log IN application in this we add a local database (db.sqlite). When new user do registration. than, add the whole data in database. its is run properly in device. But,how i see the data (data was store or not)? Question : where does this database file get stored on the filesystem when you're using an simulator (in Computer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I got my .sql file at

> /Users/myName/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/4.2/Applications/B378BED2-C67C-4465-AB8A-184D80C41D88/Library/Private
>   Documents

*B378BED2-C67C-4465-AB8A-184D80C41D88* is some random name generated by system,it would be different in your case.