# Location of database file in device for alloy titanium application

Tags: android, ios, titanium, titanium-alloy

I am new to alloy mvc framework.I was working in projects using SQLite.I kept SQLite file in asset folder and did query works in application.
               An instance of SQLite file is created in simulator folder. My question is can we see database file in ios ,android device and where it is stored in device.
    Please suggest me ..
    Thanks in advance.

Comment: for ios see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761695/where-does-the-iphone-simulator-save-the-sqllite-database)

Answer (score 0):

In Android, you can find your database at this location

```
/data/data/your.package.name/databases/your_db_name.db
```

Comment: Thanks marcus...but I don't see any database file in path you specified ....My path is like this 
data/my.package.name/cache/_tmp          
alone..
No database path in it...

Comment: You can read this folder on your emulator, but not physical device. If you want to read it on your physical device, you'll have to root it. @DineshMurugesan

Answer (score 0):

for **iOS simulator**, you can find the database at this location :

`/Users/USER_NAME/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/NOW_SELECT_YOUR_DEVICE/data/Containers/Data/Application/SELECT_YOUR_APPLICATION/Library/Private Documents/`

Normally `USER_NAME/Library` the `Library` folder is hidden, you have to unhide it first.

You can use the **Xcode's Organiser** to access the database on the **device**.

First open the Xcode's organiser, then select your device, then choose your application, now download container from below settings icon, you will get an `.xcappdata` file.

Now select the downloaded container i.e. `.xcappdata` file and `Show Package Contents`. Now go in `AppData/Library/Private Documents`. Here you will get the database of your application.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks swanand .... I could see database in simulator folder ...my question is can we see it in apple device ...is there any third party app to view database file..???